# Recursive calculator in C

Tags: c, recursion, math-expression-eval

This is a calculator I wrote for a student's project.

It still has a problem (one that I know of), where it can't handle inputs of the form `2*2*2`... (more than one `*` or `/` sign). The case `2*2` was solved in hackish ways.

I'd appreciate any remarks or advice on the code and possibly how to solve that problem.

Relevant inputs are using `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `(`, `)`, etc.

EDIT: I fixed the problems listed above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getInput(char * in) {
    printf("> ");
    fgets(in, 256, stdin);
}

int isLeftParantheses(char p) {
    if (p == '(') return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int isRightParantheses(char p) {
    if (p == ')') return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int isOperator(char p) {
    if (p == '+' || p == '-' || p == '*' || p == '/') return p;
    else return 0;
}

int performOperator(int a, int b, char p) {
    switch(p) {
        case '+': return a+b;
        case '-': return a-b;
        case '*': return a*b;
        case '/':
            if (b == 0) { printf("Can't divide by 0, aborting...\n"); exit(1); } 
            return a/b;
    }
    return 0;
}


char isDigit(char p) {
    if (p >= '0' && p <= '9') return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int charToDigit(char p) {
    if (p >= '0' && p <= '9') return p - '0';
    else return 0;
}

int isNumber(char * p) {
    while(*p) {
        if (!isDigit(*p)) return 0;
        p++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int len(char * p) {
    return int(strlen(p));
}

int numOfOperands(char * p) {
    int total = 0;
    while(*p) {
        if (isOperator(*p)) total++;
        p++;
    }
    return total+1;
}

int isMDGRoup(char * p) {

    while(*p) {
        if (!isDigit(*p) && *p != '/' && *p != '*')
            return 0;
        p++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int getLeftOperand(char * p, char * l) {
    // Grab the left operand in p, put it in l,
    //and return the index where it ends.
    int i = 0;

    // Operand is part of multi-*/ group
    if (isMDGRoup(p)) {
        while(1) {
            if (*p == '*' || *p == '/') break;
            l[i++] = *p++;
        }
        return i;
    }

    // Operand is in parantheses
    if(isLeftParantheses(*p)) {
        int LeftParantheses = 1;
        int RightParantheses= 0;
        p++;
        while(1) {
            if (isLeftParantheses(*p))  LeftParantheses++;
            if (isRightParantheses(*p)) RightParantheses++;

            if (isRightParantheses(*p) && LeftParantheses == RightParantheses)
                break;
            l[i++] = *p++;
        }
        // while (!isRightParantheses(*p)) {
        //  l[i++] = *p++;
        // }
        l[i] = '\0';
        return i+2;
    }

    // Operand is a number
    while (1) {
        if (!isDigit(*p)) break;
        l[i++] = *p++;
    }
    l[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

int getOperator(char * p, int index, char * op) {
    *op = p[index];
    return index + 1;
}

int getRightOperand(char * p, char * l) {
    // Grab the left operand in p, put it in l,
    //and return the index where it ends.
    while(*p && (isDigit(*p) || isOperator(*p) ||
                 isLeftParantheses(*p) || isRightParantheses(*p))) {
        *l++ = *p++;
    }
    *l = '\0';

    return 0;
}

int isEmpty(char * p) {
    // Check if string/char is empty
    if (len(p) == 0) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int calcExpression(char * p) {
    // if p = #: return atoi(p)
    //
    // else:
    //  L = P.LeftSide
    //  O = P.Op
    //  R = P.RightSide
    //  return PerformOp(calcExpression(L), calcExpression(R), O)

    // ACTUAL FUNCTION

    // if p is a number, return it
    if (isNumber(p)) return atoi(p);

    // Get Left, Right and Op from p.
    char leftOperand[256] = ""; char rightOperand[256]= "";
    char op;

    int leftOpIndex   = getLeftOperand(p, leftOperand);
    int operatorIndex = getOperator(p, leftOpIndex, &op);
    int rightOpIndex  = getRightOperand(p+operatorIndex, rightOperand);

    printf("%s, %c, %s", leftOperand, op, rightOperand);
    getchar();

    if (isEmpty(rightOperand)) return calcExpression(leftOperand);

    return performOperator(
        calcExpression(leftOperand),
        calcExpression(rightOperand),
        op
    );
}

int main()
{
    char in[256];
    while(1) {
        // Read input from user
        getInput(in);
        if (strncmp(in, "quit", 4) == 0) break;

        // Perform calculations
        int result = calcExpression(in);
        printf("%d\n", result);
    }
}
```

Comment: This codes doesn't compile for multiple reasons, so I am led to believe this code doesn't work.

Comment: What language is this? If true is defined do you have booleans? If so bool isEmpty(char * p){return len(p)== 0);}

Comment: @syb0rg: `gcc` can't compile it, but it compiles with `g++`.

Comment: @palacsint: This is barely C++ code, but there must be some if it cannot compile with `gcc`.

Comment: Not sure I understand, works fine for me, along with the limitations specified above.

Comment: It's not clear if this is supposed to be C or C++. Could you make the language absolutely clear, and tell us your compiler setup (e.g. which compiler and what options you are using)

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. Sorry. I intended for this to be C only, could you tell me what part is C++? Also, palacsint says he successfully compiled it using g++, so I assume that is what I'm using (Sublime Text 2). I'm sorry you can't run it for some reason, my question was mostly about the logic really. Thanks regardless.

Comment: @user2327670 Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/861517/1937270) for issues compiling C code as C++ code.  Also, if you do compile it with GCC (*not* G++) and compiler warnings, you should be able to fix it with a bit of effort.

Comment: Any idea on how this program could be modified to detect false input like --2 and calculate things like -2+2(returns 4 instead of 0), 2-2-2 (returns 0 instead of -2) ???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Things you did well on:

- Organization
- Use of comments
- Using `switch` statements instead of multiple `if-else`s.

## Things that could be improved:

#### Compilation

- I couldn't compile this program with this method written the way it is.

  > ```
  > int len(char * p) {
  >     return int(strlen(p));
  > }
  > ```

  I'm going to assume that is due to the issues of you compiling it with `g++`, and me having a strict compiler.  My compiler thinks that this code is trying to make some sort of function call instead of parsing the string length to an `int`.  Put the parentheses around the `int` instead, and it will work just fine.

  ```
  int len(char * p)
  {
      return (int) strlen(p);
  }
  ```

#### Refactoring

- You could simplify down some of your loops.

  > ```
  > int isMDGRoup(char * p) {
  >
  >     while(*p) {
  >         if (!isDigit(*p) && *p != '/' && *p != '*')
  >             return 0;
  >         p++;
  >     }
  >     return 1;
  > }
  > ```

  Use a `for` loop here instead.

  ```
  int isMDGRoup(char *p)
  {

      for(; *p; p++)
      {
          if (!isDigit(*p) && *p != '/' && *p != '*') return 0;
      }
      return 1;
  }
  ```

#### Syntax

- When you `return` variables that are performing operations on the same line as the `return`, surround them with parenthesis.

  ```
  return (i+2);
  ```
- You use some magic numbers.

  > ```
  > char in[256];
  > ```

  I see you use the number 256 in some other places as well.  Pull out that value into a `#define`d variable.

  ```
  #define BUFLEN 256
  ```
- Use [`puts()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/puts/) instead of `printf()` when you aren't formatting strings.
- Use a `default` in your `switch`.

  ```
  default:
  puts("Error message.");
  break;
  ```

#### Error handling:

- It is more common to `return 0` (or some error indicator) rather than to `exit(0)`. Both will call the registered `atexit` handlers and will cause program termination though. You have both spread throughout your code. Choose one to be consistent. Also, you should return different values for different errors, so you can pinpoint where something goes wrong in the future.
- Your program can't handle the input of non-whole numbers.

  ```
  > 7.7*6
  7, ., 7*6
  7, *, 6
  0
  >
  ```
- Your program can't handle malformed input.

  ```
  > 7a*6
  7, a, *6
  , *, 6
  0
  >
  ```
- Your program can't handle negative numbers properly

  ```
  > -5+6
  , -, 5+6
  5, +, 6
  -11
  >
  ```
- Your program can't handle whitespace.

  ```
  > 5 * 6
  5,  , *
  , *, 
  0
  >
  ```
- Your program doesn't handle no input very well.

  ```
  > 
  , 
  , 
  0
  >
  ```
- Your program can't handle numbers larger than the max size of an `int`.

  ```
  > 99999999999999*99999999999999
  9999999999999999999, *, 99999999999999
  -276447231
  >
  ```